# Server Error on saving Consent Screen

Tags: api, hybridauth, google-api-console

I am unable to save my consent screen settings if I put an email and/or a callback url into the settings. If I enter only product name, then I can, but of course this causes my app to fail. I'm using this simply to allow login with Google via Hybrid Auth module in Drupal. The Error I get on attempted login via google is:

```
Error: invalid_client
no support email

Request Details
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://www.edgeblog.info/hybridauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Google
access_type=offline
display=page
client_id=506273445956-2d25vc5ggq828h9gk0c910i4csbv52as.apps.googleusercontent.co
```

I have had no trouble getting this to work with other social networking sites.

Also Google help says I can change my primary email, but I cannot. Perhaps that is part of the issue.

Is there a working fix for this situation of saving the consent screen?

Thanks

Comment: Would like to add this is not an isolated incident. janos on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142369/google-oauth-error-invalid-client-no-support-email) was having the same issue, not being able to save his email on the consent screen setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Google Cloud console does not seem to be able to identify your account's email. You should try changing the primary email associated with the project:

> change the primary email associated with the project

In order to change the email associated with your project, you must first add another account with the email you want set as the primary email to your owners. This is set in Permissions > Add Member. After you have added another user to the permissions, they must then access the project in order to set their email as the project's email address.

Hopefully changing the email address will fix your issue.

As you mentioned, you can only set the email address to one associated with the currently signed in user. In your case, when you added your iCloud email address and responded to the email, Google detected who you were signed in as identified that it was the same account that was already associated with the project.

You must add an additional (Google) account in order to add a collaborator and change the associated email address.

A final thing to check is that an email address is set in the top of the consent screen page. This is the first item you can set in the form and is a drop down.

Finally, if all else fails, you can try configuring your project from [the classic Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you talking about if I go into the project, and then to Permissions and click Add Member? I tried adding my iCloud email address, which was my alternate email address, and it said I was already owner and couldn't accept the request. Then I removed that email as my alternate email address and tried it again, and it said it was not a valid Google account. So am I going to have to create another Google account just to do this? (edit: phrasing)

Comment: Sorry, I had thought you had multiple people collaborating on the project. Added one more thing to try...

Comment: No it's just me. This is just a super-simple app for the purpose of plugging into the API so people can log into my site via Google authentication.

Using the classic Google APIs console worked for me. Thanks!