# Google API Manager OAuth consent screen configuration Error

Tags: oauth, google-api, credentials

I've created an new project in the Google Developers Console and wanted to add OAuth 2.0 client ID Credentials for a Web Application, wich requires me to set a product name on the consent screen. Once I hit save after entering a product name on the OAuth constent screen configuration tab an error occurs and my changes are not applied:

The user request is invalid. Please check your URL and try again.

Server Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I guess the problem is name or mail related since all parameters except for poduct name and support mail address are optional. Tries all sort of strings as product name (without space, lowercase, long, short, random).

Since the error code is not mail related I'm tempted to believe that my issue isn't related to [others I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456465/server-error-on-saving-consent-screen).

Also tried to fill every optional parameter with valid URLs, but that did not help either.

Hope someone encountered a similar issue and can give me some advice. Thank you!

Comment: I've configured billig information because there is a popup visible in the top right corner of this [explanation](https://www.code-labs.io/codelabs/polymer-firebase/index.html#6)
Didn't help.

Comment: Hi Peer, were you able to fix your problem? I'm running into the very same and not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

So here's how I fixed this. Let's go on a picture adventure story to fix this little pesky Google-total-fudge-up.

I, too, created my account a long while ago as `@googlemail.com` but in the drop down only `@gmail.com` was showing:

[image: existential crisis; I exist but in the wrong format]

I tried @Peer's answer and added myself to the project again with my full `@googlemail.com` email. I did this via this URL:

https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/permissions/projectpermissions

(I include the link because I found no way to navigate to this from the too-clean-for-actual-links Google Console)

However, even after accepting the invitation, only my `@gmail` email appeared in the drop down list on the consent configuration screen, the `@googlemail.com` was still regarded as "Waiting for response" and, best of all, it still didn't save:

[image: Hello? Can I let me in, please?]

[image: Bummer]

So I did the following:

- Opened up [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
- Hit the save button on the consent form to enjoy the error one last time (and also record it in Fiddler)
- Locate the bad request in Fiddler (nice and red for us):
  [image: One of you is an imposter and I'm determined to find out]
- Enable editing on the bad request:
  [image: pass the scalpel]
- Select the `Inspectors` tab and edit the `supportEmail` field to change my email address to `@googlemail.com`:
  [image: there I fixed it]
- Right click on the bad request now it has been edited and navigate to `Replay -> Reissue Requests`:
  [image: Run, Forest, run!]

The new request worked a charm, and now when I reloaded my consent screen the settings had saved, but even better the drop down had the full `@googlemail.com` option:

[image: I finally found myself]

So I selected my `@googlemail.com` address and the save button worked happily ever after:

[image: Google, please give more coffee to your coders to avoid such grim bugs. Or alcohol. Or both. That's why the Irish invented Irish coffee; only the Irish can get drunk and sober up at exactly the same time.]

(Although apparently I am *still* waiting for my own response...)

[image: I am not me]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by switching the "@googlemail.com" address to "@gmail.com" via Gmail-settings (
https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts):
Described here: 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/159001?hl=en

After the change, the problem in the Google developers console diappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Or with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and Chrome instead of Fiddler:

- log your network traffic in Chrome (more tools - developer tools - network)
- try again to save the OAuth consent screen (in the same tab)
- search the POST request with the wrong supportEmail (xyz@gmail.com)
- use the context menu on the POST request entry in the list and select "Copy as cURL"
- paste in a terminal and change the supportEmail (to xyz@googlemail.com)

At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My E-Mail address was the problem. I've created the account a long time ago as xxx@googlemail.com account and could only select the xxx@gmail.com version. The support told me to add a second account to the project with another E-Mail address. Configured the consent screen and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My URI was the problem. But it still gave the same 400 error at the top. I had an underscore in it, but it was an internal DNS doing the routing so it didn't care. Google did.

E.g.

`` test_underscore.something.com #didn't work being added (it didn't exist)
test-hyphen.something.com` did work (it didn't exist) ``