# google drive ui integration - is it possible to open "google types"?

Tags: google-drive-api

Some time ago I developed simple webapp and integrated it with Google Drive UI with option "Allow users to create new documents using this application". Now I'm trying to modify it for user to be able right click on any file in his google drive and open it with my app (I only need id of selected files). I thought I need to write list of all types in "secondary MIME types", but when I write any google built-in type, like "application/vnd.google-apps.document" when I'm saving changes I only got error "Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later."
Am I missing something obvious, like maybe it's not possible to use google built-in types?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674606/google-api-manager-oauth-consent-screen-configuration-error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a limitation on Drive API v3.

Folder mime type (application/vnd.google-apps.folder) is working fine, though.