# How to send email using php via verified user of google?

Tags: php, oauth, gmail

In my web application, a user can login to the site with their gmail account [I achieved this via Oauth]. Now I want to send email to other users from my application,using the logged in user's gmail account. How could this be done?

My simple index.php

```
<?php

  session_start();

  require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php';

  // Replace this with you/r Google Client ID

  $client_id     = 'client id';
  $client_secret = 'client secret';
  $redirect_uri  = 'https://localhost/mail/index.php'; // Change this
  $server_key='server key';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Mail sending application");
  $client->setClientId($client_id);
  $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
  $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
  $client->setDeveloperKey($server_key);

  // We only need permissions to compose and send emails
  $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose");
  $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

  // Redirect the URL after OAuth
  if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }

  // If Access Toket is not set, show the OAuth URL
  if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  } else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  }

  if ($client->getAccessToken() && isset($_POST['message'])) {

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    // Prepare the message in message/rfc822
    try {

        // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
        $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($_POST["message"]), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($mime);
        $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print($e->getMessage());
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

  } ?>

 <?php if ( isset ( $authUrl ) ) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $authUrl; ?>">sign in</a>
 <?php } else { ?>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <textarea name="message" required></textarea>
    <input type="email" required name="to">
    <input type="text"  required name="subject">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms.htmlmail.submit();return false;">Send Mail</a>
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

it redirects me to gmail page but after that it shows me error like this instead of mail form :
401. That’s an error.

```
Error: invalid_client

no support email

Request Details
from_login=1
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
redirect_uri=https://localhost/mail/index.php
access_type=online
approval_prompt=auto
as=-4de25f3b2be1f07c
client_id=570442960066-01d3mblkltjfjjt9ivnqiki5vvanlas9.apps.googleusercontent.com
hl=en
```

Comment: use phpmailer or php's default mail()

Comment: Phrased things a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

check out [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/) from google . here are the [guides](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) on sending ..

there is also a [php client library](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads) available which is in beta.

---

check this [blog post](http://piecewiseinc.blogspot.in/2013/02/send-mail-with-gmail-smtp-and-xoauth.html) for code sample .
 check this stackoverflow discussions on the topic.

- [How to implement Gmail OAuth API to send email (especially via SMTP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602680/how-to-implement-gmail-oauth-api-to-send-email-especially-via-smtp)

Comment: i am using google api for authentication, i know same library can be use for mail purpose also. if poosible please show me the code

Comment: i am not using zend framework. i am using codeigniter

Comment: @SandhyaGor check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142369/google-oauth-error-invalid-client-no-support-email